# How to got: /private/var/mobile/Applications/_MY_UUID_/

Tags: ios, objective-c

how I got these link programmatically: /private/var/mobile/Applications/_MY_UUID_/

When I'm importing files to my app (from Open in...) the file path is: /private/var/mobile/Applications/_MY_UUID_/Documents/

But how I can get these link in app ?
thanks.

Comment: Marv, while your question seems succinct, there's no context and so I (and probably other people) can't be sure of how to help you out.  Please redo your question to add some more detail or I will be voting to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `URLsForDirectory:inDomains:` method of `NSFileManager` is used to find the location
of various common directories. For the "Documents" directory:

```
NSURL *docsUrl = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
```

Alternatively, you can use `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`:

```
NSString *docsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
```